# How can I syntax hightlight SASS with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, sass, syntax-highlighting, npm-package, highlight.js

I would like to syntax highlight my SASS code with `highlight.js` NPM package. However, I cannot get it to work.

SASS is not syntax highlighted, and the console displays this warning:

```
a
  text-decoration: none
 
CSS does work:

a {
  text-decoration: none
 }

WARN: Could not find the language 'sass', did you forget to load/include a language module?
WARN: Falling back to no-highlight mode for this block. <code class="language-sass">
a
  text-decoration: none
 </code>
```

You can check it with this snippet:

```js
hljs.highlightAll();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@highlightjs/cdn-assets@11.7.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="//unpkg.com/@highlightjs/cdn-assets@11.7.0/styles/nnfx-dark.min.css">

<p>SASS does NOT work:</p>
<pre>
 <code class='language-sass'>
a
  text-decoration: none
 </code>
</pre>

<p>CSS does work:</p>
<pre>
 <code class='language-css'>
a {
  text-decoration: none
 }
 </code>
</pre>
```

I would like to be able to do it in the next way:

```js
import 'highlight.js/styles/nnfx-light.css'
import hljs from 'highlight.js/lib/core'

import sass from 'highlight.js/lib/languages/sass'
hljs.registerLanguage('sass', sass)

hljs.highlightAll();
```

Comment: The given code is valid, what is the problem? Please read through the [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please update your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @AdrianKokot , I added a snippet to the question.

Comment: If you want to use it as es modules you have to install it as npm package, not cdn. Do you have it that way?

Comment: Yes, I installed the NPM package, but for the snippet I did it this way.

Comment: Are you getting some error or something? Because I still don't understand what's not working and why you ask question

Comment: Simply, SASS is not syntax highlighted.

Comment: I know. My question is "How can I syntax highlight SASS with Javascript?"

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [Highlight JS Support language list](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/main/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md), there is no SASS syntax available.

---

There is a [git issue](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/48) asking for it, but that only mentions the `Stylus` syntax which is partly compatible with SASS.

---

Example with the `stylus` language:

```js
hljs.highlightAll();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@highlightjs/cdn-assets@11.7.0/styles/default.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@highlightjs/cdn-assets@11.7.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@highlightjs/cdn-assets@11.7.0/languages/stylus.min.js"></script>

<pre>
    <code class='language-styl'>
a
    text-decoration: none
  
nav
    ul
        margin: 0
        padding: 0
        list-style: none

    li
        display: inline-block

    a
        display: block
        padding: 6px 12px
        text-decoration: none
    </code>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporal solution: to register SCSS as SASS with `highlight.js` NPM package:

```js
import scss from 'highlight.js/lib/languages/scss'
hljs.registerLanguage('sass', scss)
```